# Seven doors or seven hills of Lord Vishnu (Venkateshwara)

Tags: vaishnavism, moksha, venkateshwara, vishnu

What do the seven doors of Vaikuntam symbolize for us? I couldn't find any answer. I heard it in a movie that humans should cross the seven doors to finally reach the Lord.

I also read in an article from the Tirumala Tirupathi Devasthanam magazine that we should climb/cross the 7 hills of the Lord Venkateshwara to reach him. 7 hills representing 7 traits like greed, lust, anger, ego etc. but no scriptures were referenced.

So may I know which scriptures mention the 7 doors and what do they symbolize?

Comment: What if the seven doors of Vaikunta symbolise the seven chakras of the body? And crossing of the seven doors refers to being aware of these chakras? After all, realisation (enlightenment/consciousness) is the true attainment of God. And which movie did you hear this in?

Comment: and the link to the movie is- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oRZCokubdS0

Comment: I heard it in "sri satyanarayana swamy telugu movie". starting of the movie. it starts from 01:07 minutes of the movie. Yes! maybe you are right.even though I don't know about it but Self-realization can be attained by awakening Chakras also.is Chakra awakening and Kundalini awakening same? if you know about it can you please tell more about it to me that is about chakra awakening or significance of the Vaikuntam? Thank you for the comment

Comment: I'm afraid I do not have knowledge about Kundalini awakening.

Comment: Fine! If you have seen the movie can you tell me what the each door of the lord signifies?

Comment: Both are same.The Kundalini is composed of various Chakras each ascending from Mooladhara to Sahasrsara.

Answer (score 2):

Seven entrances or seven doors are a reference to the mystical plexuses or lotuses of yoga - the muldhara, svadhisthana, manipura, anahata, visuddha, ajna, and sahasrara. It is only after one has gone through each one of these lotuses that the Lord is seen.

Comment: And the reference of climbing and crossing the seven hills? I think it might be from the temple scriptures. I read it here( http://postimg.org/gallery/1danjntjk/) please read the three pages. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @Vishu The gallery you reference - first 2 pages are the same. 'Sin' is more of a Christian concept. Hindus have 8 fetters - shame, hatred, fear, pride of caste, lineage, pride in good conduct, grief, and secretiveness. The 7 sins on the page you reference resemble more what are called the 7 capital sins in Christianity. Orgen and Evagrius (early Christian theologian and early monk) defines them as actually 8 and the 'doors' through which demons can enter the body and lead one astray. Their 8 map almost exactly to the 7 you reference. Not aware of any sruti text that refers to 7 sins.

Comment: ohh! thank you! that magazine(Saptagiri) is a monthly from tirumala devasthanam you can get it from ebooks.tirumala.org. If sin is christian concept then I think adharmam(going against vedas/scriptures) would be our concept. btw here is the 1st picture (http://s19.postimg.org/im2kg7l0j/image.png).

Answer (score 0):

There are 14 "Lokas" or universes mentioned in Hindu scriptures. 6 are below or on one side of the universe we live in and 7 are above or on the other side. The 7 universes above are referred to as Bhu:, Bhuva: Suva: Maha: Jana: Thapa: and Satya Loka. This is there in Gayatri Mantra too. Each door opens to an universe. When you pass through each of the universe above, after passing through the 7th door, you reach Satya Loka or the Brahman or Lord Vishnu. I think that is the significance of going through the Sapta Dwara to get the Darshan of Lord Vishnu.

Comment: Welcome! You should cite sources. Please visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/3500)